# What does "Event Marker" refer to in sleep (PSG) study?

Tags: sleep

I am an engineer working on PSG studies datasets.

The particular [dataset](https://academic.oup.com/sleep/article/18/7/557/2749691) that I'm looking at has recorded 2 EEG channels, eye movement (HEOG), chin EMG, body temp and respiration and an event marker!

One thing that I don't quite understand is what the term "Event Marker" refers to? since you have the scored hypnogram, what does this event marker point out to?

This makes sense in Holter monitors since it points out to epochs through which palpitations are sensed by the patient.

Comment: I have to agree with Bryan Kraus' answer. It appears to be a general "comment" field often found included in many data sets. How can anyone other than the study authors answer this question?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't mean anything without more information from the data source. An event marker is just that...it marks events. Those events could be triggered by another device (like with a TTL pulse), could be marked manually by an operator, triggered by the patient, anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i edited the question and added the link for the study I am referring to, and it does not mention anything in particular about this event marker.

Comment: @AliKavoosi Then you probably won't be able to use it without asking the authors for more info. It's possible you can guess based on when it shows events, but do so at your own peril.